# Batch script connect to ftp sever?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to connect to my ftp server by running a batch script. I can log into it fine by typing the following:

```
ftp home.ptd.net
USERNAME
PASSWORD
cd Public
put FILENAME.txt
bye
```

But if I put this into a script in this order, it connects to the server, but still asks for a username. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to make it login? Thanks.

Comment: For added flexibility I would recommend you to use the PowerShell (from Microsoft) or FtpScripter, a scriptable file transfer software for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see the following msdn article:
[ftp reference from msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx?mfr=true)

i think you need to place the commands in a text file and pass it to the ftp command with the -s parameter

Comment: Does anyone know what to write in the text document to login to the FTP server?

Comment: try the [user](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx?mfr=true) command